# Using equals with string in enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, equals

Assume we have the next enum and I want to add equals(String) method to it, because other people that working with the same code usually make a mistake comparing enum with string using equals method.

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    CONSTANT1("DATABASE_CONSTANT1"),
    CONSTANT2("DATABASE_CONSTANT2");

    private final String databaseConstant;

    SomeEnum(String databaseConstant) {

        this.databaseConstant = databaseConstant;
    }

    public String getDatabaseConstant() {
        return databaseConstant;
    }

    public boolean equals(String databaseConstant) {
        return getDatabaseConstant().equals(databaseConstant);
    }
}
```

Question: are there any pitfalls in using the approach like this?

Comment: it's rather a problem of the people who make such mistakes

Comment: Adding new methods to work around coworkers novice coding mistakes feels wrong to me. Also this method will only work in some cases. It won't work when they are calling the equals method from the string method as in `"DATABASE_CONSTANT1".equals(SomeEnum.CONSTANT1)` or if the original equals method of the enum is called.

Comment: Honestly, it's cleaner to just throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from that method to avoid running into more problems later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the contracts bound to `equals(..)` would be violated.
Especially **symmetry**. This can lead to all kinds of problems in the future.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

I recommend not to support the miss use of `equals(..)` *'other people'* do.

To find code early that use equals(String ) you could do this:

```
@Deprecated
public boolean equals(String databaseConstant) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Never use equals(String) for SomeEnumtype "); 
}
```

The `@Deprecated` will most IDE mark any call as a warning.

---

**UPDATE**
As [davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809936/480894) wrote in his comment & answer if you use e.g. *sonar* the warning of sonar would be sufficient to cope with your problem without adding the 'dead code' I offered as a solution above.

Comment: While a clever trick, I find that adding dead code is not a good practice. Code quality tools are designed to.

Comment: @davidxxx: I agree, but this was the most practical thing I could come up with. If you can recommend a tool, which does the trick, Please share it with us.

Comment: Sonar does that : "https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-2159". My answer refers to.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this method to avoid bad uses of a standard method as `equals()` is not advised.
Besides, even if you added this method in your `SomeEnum` class, you cannot and don't want to do the same thing in the `String` class!
So `"DATABASE_CONSTANT1".equals(SomeEnum.DATABASE_CONSTANT1)` is still possible and will not return what you would like.

I think that Lint and code analysis tool as Sonar are better to handle bad practices.

For example, Sonar defines the [**Silly equality checks should not be made**](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-2159) bug rule.
This makes multiple checks about the `equals()` usage which you need :

> comparing unrelated classes

Here is more detail about it :

> Comparisons of dissimilar types will always return false. The
>   comparison and all its dependent code can simply be removed. This
>   includes:
>
> comparing an object with null
>
> comparing an object with an unrelated primitive (E.G. a string with an
>   int)
>
> **comparing unrelated classes**
>
> comparing an unrelated class and interface
>
> comparing unrelated interface types
>
> comparing an array to a non-array
>
> comparing two arrays